# Increments in Derivatives

Tags: derivatives

Say, I have an equation $y^2=x^3$.
So I can say $dy^2/dx=3x^2$.
So the very small increment in $y^2$ when $x$ becomes $dx$ is $dy^2$ which in this case is $3x^2dx$. 
I also know that $dy^2/dy=2y$ so I can say $dy^2=2ydy$ and equate the increments but how do I know the increments $dy^2$ are same in both the cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the second equation you obtained by $dx$ on both sides
$$\frac{dy^2}{dx} = 2y \frac{dy}{dx}$$
Then substitute the values $y = x^{\frac 32}$ and $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{x}$, which are obtained from the initial equation $y^2 = x^3$. This gives you 
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx} = 3x^2$$
which is identical to equation 1.

Comment: *but how do I know the increments $dy^2$ are same in both cases* - I answered this question.